# Return scrapy items after the spider is done

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to somehow scrape a number of items, save them to list and when the spider is done, all items will be returned for pipeline management.
I've tried something similar do this with the code below, but it doesn't work since Scrapy doesn't expect items to be returned in the function `Spider.closed()`.

I need to do this because I scrape two search lists that have products in common and extract data from them both, so I would like the same product from two diffrent search lists to be saved in one item.

I've solved this previously with the kind off hacky solution of running some function after each `parse()` to check if the other parse is done. But this gave some unexpected results.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     items = []

def parse(self, response):
    ...
    newitem = Item()
    self.items.append(newitem)


def closed(self, reason):
    for item in self.items:
         yield item
```

Comment: It's hard to give specifics without a minimal reproducible exmple but could you not instantiate an item object, scrape the first search list of the data you need in a function, then pass that items object to another function to crawl the second search list of the data of the unique data. A pipeline could be created to check for duplicate data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, a bit hacky as well but it works.
This is maybe not the best solution though, since it seems like scrape doesn't regonize the items that has been processed. Could have implications for deployment later.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    items = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        from_crawler = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler
        spider = from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def idle(self):
        itemproc = self.crawler.engine.scraper.itemproc
        for item in self.items:
            itemproc.process_item(item, self)
```